# How to convert this SQL query to Fetch XML?

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, dataverse

Is it possible to write this SQL query as a Fetch XML query? http://www.sql2fetchxml.com fails to convert this query.

```
select a.ownerid, b.call_count
from opportunity a
join (
select vsg_loan, count(*) as 'call_count'
from phonecall
group by vsg_loan
having count(*) = 2) b
on a.opportunityid = b.vsg_loan
order by b.call_count
```

I expect the result to be something like this...

[image: sample output]

Comment: Looks like FetchXML doesn't support subtables, but you can rewrite this query to just use joins instead of subtables. Which is actually what the answer below does.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, that issue is solvable. But the main issue here is that Fetch XML doesn't seem to support 'having' or equivalent keyword for filtering on aggregate values.

Comment: Yep you're right, this article also implies it doesn't exist https://markcarrington.dev/2019/12/17/inside-fetchxml-pt-5-aggregate/ You probably need to either go with TDS endpoint as mentioned in the other answer, or use some kind of replication solution to replicate data into a local database that you can query.

Answer (score 2):

Dataverse now has a [TDS endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query), so you can just use that query directly.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Thank you! We are already aware of this possibility. But in my case, if this was possible with Fetch XML itself then it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

There should be something working like this , I hope this works for you mate :)

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
      <entity name="opportunity" alias="a">
        <attribute name="ownerid" />
        <link-entity name="phonecall" from="vsg_loan" to="opportunityid" alias="b" link-type="inner">
          <attribute name="vsg_loan" aggregate="countcolumn" alias="call_count" />
          <filter>
            <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" /> <!-- Optional: Filter based on phone call state if needed -->
          </filter>
          <attribute name="vsg_loan" groupby="true" />
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="vsg_loan" operator="not-null" /> <!-- Optional: Exclude records where vsg_loan is null -->
          </filter>
          <having>
            <condition attribute="vsg_loan" operator="eq" value="2" /> <!-- Adjust the count value as needed -->
          </having>
        </link-entity>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like 'having' is valid keyword. Getting the error, 

`Invalid Child Node, valid values are: filter, order or link-entity. NodeName = having NodeXml = <having>
        <condition attribute="vsg_loan" operator="eq" value="2" />
        <!-- Adjust the count value as needed -->
      </having>`